# testng specify different Users

Tags: maven, junit, testng

I am running our automated tests using TestNG.  The reason we picked TestNG is because we can send variables inputs into the test methods example **public void testXX( String userId )** and the userId can change for each test.

The code below shows three different userIds I can use to execute my tests.  So my exact same test will run three times for each of the three different users.  This feature is awesome and really enables me to have multiple tests under different scenarios because each of our users carry different profiles.

```
// All valid Pricing Leads
@DataProvider(name = "userIds")
public Object[][] createPricingLeadUsersParameters() {
   return new Object[][] {
      { "TestUser001" },
      { "TestUser002" },
      { "TestUser003" }
   };
}

@Test( dataProvider = "userIds" )
public void createGroup( String userIds) {
    ............
 }
```

The problem I am having right now is during certain conditions I can only have one userId used or else all of my tests will fail.  I would like to keep my exact same test but only pass in on userId not the three shown above.  It there a way to configure TestNG to make this variable on the command line so at times I would use the three defined, but under another condition it would only be one of the three or a new userId?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there are plenty of ways to do this. How about passing a system property when you run TestNG?

```
java -Dfoo=bar org.testng.TestNG...
```

and then your data provider can test the value of `foo` with `System.getProperty()` and adjust what it returns accordingly.

Comment: I need a way to set the userIds based on one configuration over the other.  Was hoping to have some way the TestNG would control this via say the testng.xml versus programatically doing this.  Thanks for input!